# UTF-16 Surrogate Pairs in Java JNDI LDAP Calls

Tags: utf-8, ldap, jndi, utf-16, apacheds

I am seeing exceptions when issuing [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) calls that include UTF-16 surrogate pairs. Here is some example Java code:

```java
DirContext context = getContext();
String name = "\u5653\ud840\udc0b";
// String name = "渚噓"; //Same result if I use the actual characters
String distinguishedName = "cn=" + name + ",ou=users,dc=example,dc=com";
Attribute objectClass = new BasicAttribute("objectClass", "person");
Attribute userSn = new BasicAttribute("sn", "sn");

Attributes entry = new BasicAttributes();
entry.put(userSn);
entry.put(objectClass);

context.createSubcontext(distinguishedName, entry);
```

Results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 80 - OTHER: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
: ERR_13247_INVALID_VALUE_CANT_NORMALIZE Invalid upValue, it can't be normalized:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERR_13247_INVALID_VALUE_CANT_NORMALIZE Invalid upValue, it can't be normalized
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value.<init>(Value.java:379)
```

The same code works if I remove the surrogate pair (\ud840\udc0b). This would appear to be a limitation of [*The Apache Directory™ Project (ApacheDS)*](https://directory.apache.org/), the local [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) server I'm using. However, I've tested with other LDAP implementations (eg. IBM Tivoli Directory Server) and also get errors:

```
javax.naming.InvalidNameException: cn=噓,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com: [LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN Syntax]
```

and:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for cn=噓,dc=example,dc=com]; remaining name 'cn=噓,dc=example,dc=com'
```

In each test, everything functions correctly when I remove the surrogate pairs. Is there a limitation in LDAP?

Comment: You should list those "other LDAP implementations".

Comment: Decode the `"\u5653\ud840\udc0b"` string to `"噓"` i.e.  `噓` (U+5653,  *CJK Ideograph*) and `` (U+2000B, *CJK Ideograph Extension B (0xd840,0xdc0b)*) in detail. Algorithm in [The WTF-8 encoding](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) (*4.2 Decoding*).